# Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xA0 0x20 0x42 0x72 in - google geocoder

Tags: php, xml, google-maps

Can you please help me out on this? I have a big list with addresses to geocode and it keeps giving this error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]:
>   http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&key=KEY&q=928+Broadway%A0+Brooklyn%2C+11206+%2C+:3:
>   parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes:
>   0xA0 0x20 0x42 0x72 in

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your input is not a UTF-8 document. 0xA0 would be a following byte of a 2- to 4-byte sequence (0xA0 is `10100000`, all initial bytes start with `11`, and all one-byte characters start with a zero), but here it's shown as the leading byte.

This likely means that your document is either corrupted (according to the XML definitions, it is not well formed) or it was created using a *codepage* (or, very unlikely, UTF-16).

You will have to inform your XML parser how to translate characters outside the 0-128 ASCII range, or remove the errant byte sequences as you see fit.

An alternative is to use a more tolerant parser such as Beautiful Soup.

You should be very glad you got the error message - the only other thing that could happen is silent corruption.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by %A0 which is Latin-1 for non-breaking space. For English it probably would suffice to replace this by a space (encoded as `+`); here it could be deleted.

You can do `utf8_encode($city)` too.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to the Google Maps API [Geocoding Web Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/). Your request would look something like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=928+Broadway+Brooklyn+11206&sensor=true&key=KEY
```